# Amazon SNS - Sending SMS, delivery status

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

I am trying to send messages using Amazon SNS but it's showing atypical behavior. It sends messages to some of the numbers while may or may not to others.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns', .....)
client.publish(PhoneNumber, Message)
```

I am using the publish API to directly send SMS for OTPs without using Topics. Is there a way I can get the delivery status for them? Would region/DND affect the delivery. This is for Indian numbers. I am using Transactional messages for the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the console there is 'Text Messaging Preferences'. One needs to set up, **IAM role for CloudWatch Logs access** and **Report Storage** bucket. Once they are set up, Amazon will start storing logs in CloudWatch. Once done it will start showing delivery rates and status in the console UI and detailed logs in CloudWatch.

There are multitudes of reason for which delivery may fail. It lists out all on them. DND can also affect the delivery even if message type is `transactional`.

Also there is a availalble API to query these logs accordingly. 
[image]

Comment: Yes, looks like you need to parse CloudWatch logs to find out if a particular SMS delivery failed: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html

Comment: @sakovias is there any change on this? Is parsing logs is still the only way to get sms delivery status?