# aws sns - handle SMS delivery failures

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We are using AWS SNS to send SMS messages to our clients. when a sms message is fail to be sent, I want to handle it somehow (the best is to call a lambda function with the event).

The only way I found is to enable cloudWatch logs and read them once in a while. the problem is that looking for a specific messageId in the logs takes ages.

Is there and way to trigger a lambda, or to insert message to sqs or do any active operation the can activate my logic when a delivery is failed?

Comment: That would be nice but the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668417/amazon-sns-sending-sms-delivery-status) is apparently still accurate.  You've got to parse the logs.